# OpenOffice Impress (MS Powerpoint alternative) not linking to Projector

Tags: display, openoffice.org, presentation, slideshow, projector

When i connect OpenOffice ppt for projector, it doesnt display or detect anything.While i can run the same in my windows OS installed alongside. I donot know if it is a possible driver problem or a software problem. Please help incase someone has solved such a problem.

Comment: I'd say it is not a problem with Impress, rather with VGA output redirecting in Ubuntu.

Comment: So you mean to say it is a bug or depends on the system configuration or something?

Comment: I'd say this is a small config issue with monitors. Otherwise, you'll need to try different graphics drivers. Did you use a `nomodeset` workaround to get Ubuntu to work in the first place(You'll know if you did, otherwise, you may not have heard of the workaround)

Comment: It is not clear from your question, whether you actually did anything else apart from plugging in the projector? Ubuntu does not automatically switch additional displays on: on my laptop I have to press Fn+F8 in order to do that. Did you do something like this?

Comment: Nope ... I was looking for it to detect the device and ask for a connection or atleast a popup or directly start displaying in case the device is compatible... I didnt try any of the above... rather didnt know abt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an external monitor / projector is plugged in, Ubuntu does not automatically switch it on. Normally, you can do this by pressing a key combination which depends on the keyboard you are using. Often its `Fn+F8` or something similar, often containing two displays.

You can also click on `[System Menu] -> Display...`:
[image]

which brings up a dialog like this:

[image]

There you can fine tune the configuration you like. (relative position of the monitors etc.)

Note: LibreOffice has nothing to do with this.